# Python not putting out actual result

Tags: python

I'm currently compiling a list with only the ESSID of all available networks in the area to be used for another purpose.

This is the script:

```
from subprocess import check_output
scanoutput = check_output(["iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"])

for line in scanoutput.split():
        if line.startswith("ESSID:"):
                line=line[7:-1]
                print line
```

When I run the command "sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID" from the SSH, this is the output:

```
            ESSID:"easybell DSL"
            ESSID:"FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7360 SL_EXT"
            ESSID:"NoTrespassing"
            ESSID:"WLAN-519293"
            ESSID:"Cinque"
            ESSID:"EasyBox-738461"
            ESSID:"FRITZ!Box WLAN 3270"
            ESSID:"EasyBox-A2B246"
```

Sadly, the Python script outputs:

```
easybel
FRITZ!Bo
NoTrespassing
WLAN-519293
Cinque
EasyBox-738461
FRITZ!Bo
EasyBox-A2B246
```

With a closer inspection it looks like it borks out when there is a space, but it also seems to remove one last letter before the space before printing it. Can someone explain what is going on here?

As far as I can tell is from the code

```
line=line[7:-1]
```

is the 7 responsible to remove the first 7 characters, thus: ESSID:" and the -1 is responsible from the last " thus resulting in a clean line with just the SSID name.

When I run the code without this line this is the output:

```
ESSID:"easybell
ESSID:"NoTrespassing"
ESSID:"WLAN-519293"
ESSID:"Cinque"
ESSID:"EasyBox-738461"
ESSID:"FRITZ!Box
ESSID:"FRITZ!Box
```

How is it possible that a from the SSH line I can get the proper information, but when I have python run the code it looses parts?

Any way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's probably the `split():` and `line=line[7:-1]` that are causing it

Comment: Yep, exactly. `line=line[7:-1]` removes the last character and `line=line[7:]` gives you the line from character 7 (8 if not zero-indexed) to the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) by default cuts on any whitespace, you need to explicitly set the `split()` separator to `\n`:

> *string.split(s[, sep[, maxsplit]])*: If the optional second argument sep is absent or `None`, the words are separated by arbitrary strings of whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, return, formfeed)

```
>>> test = '''
ESSID:"easybell DSL"
ESSID:"FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7360 SL_EXT"
ESSID:"NoTrespassing"
[...]
'''
>>> for l in test.split():
...     if l.startswith('ESSID'):
...         print(l[7:-1])
...         
easybel
FRITZ!Bo
NoTrespassing
[...]
>>> for l in test.split('\n'):
...     if l.startswith('ESSID'):
...         print(l[7:-1])
...         
easybell DSL
FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7360 SL_EXT
NoTrespassing
[...]
```

Or use [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
>>> for l in test.splitlines():
...     if l.startswith('ESSID'):
...         print(l[7:-1])
...         
easybell DSL
FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7360 SL_EXT
NoTrespassing
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `split()` on the output, which splits on any whitespace (not just line breaks), hence `line` is actually getting set to `ESSID:"easybell` and then `DSL"` and then `ESSID:"FRITZ!Box`, etc.  Note that as the final `"` is not present in the same word as `ESSID`, `line[7:-1]` ends up cutting off the last character in `ESSID:"easybell`, so you end up with `easybel`.  What you want to do instead is `for line in scanoutput.splitlines():`.

Answer (score 1):

This won't remove the last character (only the starting/ending quotes). Doing `line = line.strip()` ensures that `startswith("ESSID:")` won't fail because of white-space before "ESSID:".

```
from subprocess import check_output
scanoutput = check_output(["iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"])
for line in scanoutput.split("\n"):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("ESSID:"):
        line=line[7:-1]
        print line
```